# Nginx: Rewrite folder to folder2

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need to do a simple rewrite, and can't find out how.

Rewrite "http://example.com/"index.php/administrator/catalog_product/new/"dumpidum"
to "http://example.com/"index.php/administrator/catalog_product/new/set/4/type/simple/"dumpidum"

What I found out is:

```
rewrite /index\.php/administrator/catalog_product/new/(.*)$ /index.php/administrator/catalog_product/new/set/4/type/simple/$1;
```

But this isn't working as expected.

note: apache2 code would be:

```
Redirect 302 /index.php/administrator/catalog_product/new/key/ http://example.com/index.php/administrator/catalog_product/new/set/4/type/simple/key/
```

Does someone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm desperate to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for a rewrite, but your Apache example is a redirect. Unless you specify otherwise, nginx will do a rewrite on relative paths. You need to specify the `redirect` flag to the [`rewrite`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) directive in order to send a redirect.

```
rewrite ^/index\.php/administrator/catalog_product/new/(.*)$ /index.php/administrator/catalog_product/new/set/4/type/simple/$1 redirect;
```